# Need hostname verification while making SSL connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to validate there 4 things while making an SSL connection

1. Hostname in the URL matches CN and SAN Certificate
2. Cert presented by server is signed by CA in trust store
3. Server Cert is not expired
4. CA cert is not expired

Code:

```
options.withT1s(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderT1sParameters()
{
    CertificationValidationCallBack=(cer, chain, error, o) =>
    {
        if(//do checks here)
        {
          //    check pass
              return true;
        }
        else
        {
          //   check fail
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those four checks are done by the system already.  If you had no custom callback that's exactly what would be enforced for you.

In a custom callback the state of those is represented by the `error` and `chain` parameters... `error` is a [Flags] value.

If `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` is set then the name didn't match the SAN entries (or CN entries if there were no SAN-DNS entries) -- your condition (1).

If `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` is set then the `chain` object will indicate why it wasn't valid (something was expired, the root was not trusted, and a lot more potential problems).

So, the easiest answer (after not registering a callback) is `return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;`

Comment: Can you please explain this to me using code language like above sample

Comment: @HarjotSingh `CertificationValidationCallBack = (cer, chain, error, o) => error == SslPolicyErrors.None`.  Or `if (error == SslPolicyErrors.None)` is your success check.

Comment: And also where can I confirm if these check are already done by the system. This will really help